# String.matches confusion

Tags: java

So I'm using the .matches method that looks like this

```
    desc.matches("[0-9a-z A-Z]+")
```

but whenever I feed it "100 Thumbtacks" it returns false. I'm confused as to why

Edit:

So I'm fairly new to posting question sorry about that, but I'll share my code with a better description. So I am scanning a file ("Inventory.txt") in my main class that creates and array of InventoryItem objects. My issue is I keep getting my argument exception when I call the .setDescription method.

Main:

```
public static void main (String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException
{
  InventoryItem[] inventory = new InventoryItem[100];
  PrintStream newF = new PrintStream("receipts.txt");
  Scanner file = new Scanner( new File("Inventory.txt"));
  int count = 0;

  while(file.hasNextLine())
  {
     inventory[count] = new InventoryItem();
     inventory[count].setItemID(file.nextLine());
     inventory[count].setDescription(file.nextLine());
     while(file.hasNextDouble())
     {
        inventory[count].setPrice(file.nextDouble());
     }
     file.nextLine();
     count++;
  } 
}
```

InventoryItem class:

```
public class InventoryItem {
private String itemID = "0A";
private String description = "fill";
private double price = 0.0;

public InventoryItem()
{
   itemID = "TBD";
   description = "TBD";
   price = 0.0;
}
public InventoryItem(String itemID, String desc, double price)
{
   setDescription(desc);
   setItemID(itemID);
   setPrice(price);
}  

public void setItemID(String id)
{
   if(id.matches("[0-9a-zA-Z]+"))
   {
      itemID = id;
   }
   else
   {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("ID must contain at least one letter or  one digit and only letters or digits");
   }
}

public void setDescription(String desc)
{
   if(desc.matches("[0-9a-z A-Z]+"))
   {
      description = desc;
   }
   else
   {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Description must contain letters");
   }
}

public void setPrice(double price)
{
   if(price < 0)
   {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Price must be non-negative");
   }
   else
   {
      this.price = price;
   }
}

public String getItemID()
{
   return itemID;
}

public String getDescription()
{
   return description;
}

public double getPrice()
{
   return price;
}
```

}

and the txt file just contains stuff like:

111A

100 Thumbtacks

5.95

25

Edit: I think I found the problem. In the txt file for when it grabs a "description" there is a "-" which my .matches does not allow. My bad guys but thanks for the help! lol

Comment: You're doing something wrong. `System.out.println("100 Thumbtacks".matches("[0-9a-z A-Z]+"));` prints `true`.

Comment: Returns `true` for me.

Comment: This returns true for me..

Answer (score 1):

`desc` must be not what you think it is (it's not "`100 Thumbtacks`"):

```
String desc = "100 Thumbtacks";
System.out.println(desc.matches("[0-9a-z A-Z]+")); // prints "true"
```

Before checking `desc` with `matches()` try to `System.out.println(desc);` or even:

```
for(char c : desc.toCharArray()) {
    System.out.println(c + " - ASCII code: " + (int) c);
}
```

It will provide you a list of all **ASCII codes** assigned to characters used in `desc` String - you can check if this list contains character that is not contained in the following character class: `[0-9a-z A-Z]`. To see a list of ASCII codes you can search the Internet, e.g. [this ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com).

1. digits from 0 to 9 have ASCII codes from 48 to 57
2. characters from a to z: from 97 to 122
3. characters from A to Z: 65 to 90, and *maybe the most important character here*:
4. space: 32.

If in the list that is printed with for loop that I showed earlier there is any ASCII code not listed here, `String.matches()` returns `false`. (Thank you **dave_thompson_085** for valuable suggestion).

Comment: Some wrong characters may not be visible when printed, like CR, NBSP, soft-hyphen, (redundant) left-to-right, (nonstandard) BOM, or at least not easily visible, like Cyrillic letters.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Of course you're right. I edited my answer and I would appreciate if you could say a word if that kind of checking ASCII codes is acceptable in OP's case and if it can help in finding a problem with `String.matches()` returning `false`. Thank you for giving these explanations.